# Equation of straight lines perpendicular to each other

Tags: geometry

If the equation of a line is given by , $2x-3y+7=0$, then why is the equation of a line perpendicular to it given by $3x+2y=c$ ? I understand that the slope of the first line is $\frac{2}{3}$ hence the slope of the second line will be $-\frac{3}{2}$ where $3$represents the coefficient of $x$ and $2$ represents the coefficient of $y$ , but it’s also possible that the coefficient of$x$ and $y$ could be multiples of $3$ and $2$ ? Like $-\frac{6}{4}$

Comment: The slope is $-a/b$ when the equation is in the form $ax+by=c,b\ne 0$ so it doen't really matter which are $a$ and $b$ because the ratio is important. Hope it is clear...

Comment: -6/4 = -3/2, they are the same number ( so the same slope)

Comment: @eigenjohnson , so does it represent the same line then ?

Comment: @Amanda yes, it does!

Comment: @famesyasd okay thanks !

Comment: @Amanda Draw a couple of lines and see for yourself!